# Is there a custom workflow studio that can easily integrate in to my website?

Tags: workflow

I'm looking for some help with finding a custom workflow studio on my website. I want to allow users to select allowed actions (supported as rest API) as drag and drop function, design them as workflows and publish them. for example,our web app supports inventorying hardware resources, and users can select a resource and perform specific actions such as patching, software updates, running compliance tests, and scheduling, etc.,via back-end APIs. I am looking for a workflow studio (preferably opensource, paid is fine as well) that allow customers to create workflows to define a sequence of specific actions and publish them. Once published,customers should be able to monitor the state of the workflows.

Looking for a solution